# can't connect to wifi after Arch Linux installation

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, wpa-supplicant

I just finished installing Arch Linux on my computer. Everything seems to be working fine, except I can't get my wifi to work. My wifi is a standard WPA2 network that comes from a router in my house. I know I should be able to get it to work because when I boot the Arch installation USB, I can get it working using `wifi-menu`.

I'm following the Arch Wiki's [Network configuration/Wireless](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration/Wireless) page. In order to be systematic, I started by only installing the `wpa-supplicant` package. Following the steps on the Arch Wiki, the command `lspci -k` says the *Kernel driver in use* and *Kernel modules* are both `rtl8192ce` which should be correct for my wifi adapter. Next, my interface is wlp5s0 and I set it to "UP" using `ip link set wlp5s0 up`. Next, the `dmesg | grep firmware` command showed the following error:

```
# dmesg | grep firmware
...
[    1.953242] platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
...
```

So I installed [wireless-regdb](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/any/wireless-regdb/) which fixed that error, but did not make the wifi work. Next, I tried to connect to the wifi by following the Arch Wiki's [wpa_supplicant](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wpa_supplicant) page. I followed the `wpa_cli` step as shown on the wiki:

```
# wpa_cli
> scan
> scan_results
```

The last command showed my wifi network. I then followed the rest of the steps on the wiki, but the internet connection still doesn't work (I'm using `ping` to test the connection).

**How can I get my wifi working?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out myself. I guess I didn't thoroughly follow the `wpa_supplicant` page on the Arch Wiki. The problem was that I needed to install the `dhcpcd` package and then start/enable the dhcpcd service: `systemctl start dhcpcd.service`. See the Arch Wiki's [dhcpcd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/dhcpcd) page for more info.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov One can only mark his own answer as solved 48 h after the question.